# Semantic Macro - assigning a previous macro to another

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I have this macro:

```
#define kPaxZoneW 105.0
```

I want to define a subsequent macro that always needs to have the same value but for semantic reasons, needs to have a different name.  Can I get away with this after the previous definition?

```
#define kPaxZoneAFA kPaxZoneW
```

This would ensure that kPaxZoneAFA will always be equal to the value of kPaxZoneW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; when you do this, any use of `kPaxZoneAFA` would be replaced first by `kPaxZoneW` then by `105.0`.

Comment: on a side note, preprocessing is done in 1 pass, so order is really important... if not in the same header file, you need to pay attention that they get always included in the same order.

Comment: @Bruce:  The order of the macro definitions does not matter so long as both macros are defined before they are used.  Macro replacement is lazy.

Comment: good to know! I had been painfully diligent in macro ordering

Comment: true it's lazy until you use it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. When the preprocessor comes across your second declaration, it will assign it the value of your original macro.

This is done in most every framework for aliases to macros.